# Setting a value on existing tag metadata field when that tag was just created by a user

Tags: tags

I have extra metadata (true/false) for taxonomy terms. What I'm trying to accomplish is give this field a value for new terms created by users (it doesn't matter if that value is true or false, just matters theres a value).

This tag metadata field would act as a "flag" for these term, letting me know that they were created by someone other than me. I then would be easily able to prevent those terms from being loaded again for other users before I looked at them.

You could think of it as quality control.

Comment: I suppose a proceeding question is whether you can link an author/creator of a given tag to that tag (I'm referring to tags added via a frontend form by a user). I'm pretty surprised I haven't come across this question on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to add a meta value on a term creation, you can use that :

```
const TAXONOMIE_SLUG = "category";

add_action("create_" . TAXONOMIE_SLUG, function ($term_id, $tt_id) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    update_term_meta($term_id, "creationUser", $user->ID);

}, 10, 2);
```